# sudo mv fails with "Operation not permitted"

Tags: mac-osx, sudo

When I command on my MacOS:

```
> sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-52
```

I get the result:

```
mv: rename /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/php-52: Operation not permitted
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ensure that target partition mounted as readwrite?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Must be due to the flags - try  `sudo chflags nouchg /usr/bin/php`

EDIT:

You need to press Cmd + R at boot time, open the terminal and then run csrutil disable and reboot.

Comment: Nothing changes: the command doesn't give any result; the operation is still not permited.

Comment: What does `lsattr /usr/bin/php` show?

Comment: I suppose in OS X (I gave this info only in the tag...) the command is "ls -lO"
The result is: -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  restricted,compressed 10577504 Dec  3 06:35 php

Comment: Assuming you're running El Capitan, you need to press Cmd + R at boot time, open the terminal and then run `csrutil disable`  and reboot. Should work after that. Can this question be moved to superuser.com? Not sure how to do it myself.

Comment: Yes, this worked! And the "chflags nouchg" wasn't necessary. Can you edit your answer to give this direct instruction?... Then I will accept it! I cannot move this to superuser.com .